# In Producer/Consumer, why does switching the order of up(mutex) and up(fill) result in deadlock?

Tags: deadlock, semaphore, producer-consumer

Let's use the code on the wikipedia page as the example.

```
semaphore mutex = 1;
semaphore fillCount = 0;
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE;

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem();
        down(emptyCount);
            down(mutex);
                putItemIntoBuffer(item);
            up(mutex);
        up(fillCount);
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount);
            down(mutex);
                item = removeItemFromBuffer();
            up(mutex);
        up(emptyCount);
        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

Why does swapping the position of up(mutex) and up(fillCount) in the producer function guarantee deadlock? I'm trying to come up with an instance, but can't seem to find any.